# Converting ListBuffer[List[Any] ] Any type elements to inferred types

Tags: scala, list, dictionary

I created a `ListBuffer[ List[Any]] ()` that has following output:

```
   for (x <- list_buff){
        println(x)
    }

/** =======OutPut==================
    List(List(i), List(feel))
    List(List(feel), List(good))
    List(List(good), List(when))
    List(List(when), List(i))
    List(List(i), List(am))
    ............
=================**/
```

So its a `List[List[String],List[String]]` so type inference should figure it out. However, when I try to apply List methods such as `map()`, `isEmpty`, or even `toList`, I get errors like the methods cannot work on type `Any`. Moreover, I am unsuccessful to use the general `toList` method as well. How can I resolve this? I tried using `ListBuffer[ List[ List[String],List[String] ] ]` for definition but it says `List` only takes one parameter.

Comment: `Any` is generally a symptom of design issues

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the question, but I assume you created a List of Lists of Strings, annotated it as Lists of Lists of Any and you wonder why the types aren't matching.

Several things:

- `List` indeed takes only one parameter. `List(List("a", "b"), List("c", "d"))` has a type `List[List[String]]` not `List[List[String], List[String]]`
- the fact that `toString` at runtime prints what it prints is a result of how `List`'s `toString` work: `s"List(${elements.mkString(", ")})"`. It doesn't mean the compiler knows the type
- compiler infers the type from the things it knows during compile time. If you create a function returning `List[List[Any]]` it has no right to "guess" that it will be `List[List[String]]`. If it was `val x = List(List("a", "b"), List("c", "d"))` then it will infer the type as you want.

Basically, type inference doesn't magically guess what you have there. It calculates the most specific type given the information about variables, constants and functions, "greatest common denominator" colloquially (or "least upper bound" specifically).

If you didn't annotate the values and you ended up with Any, then you have some problem with the code (you didn't shown) - Any is a supertype of all other types (top-type), and if it appears as inferred type it means compiler had to infer a common part of things that have nothing in common, so most likely you messed something up (e.g. `List("a", 1)` would become `List[Any]`).